# Use Ubuntu One account to purchase from 7digital website?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-one

Is there a way to transfer 7digital account info to Songbird on windows. I've purchased music in ubuntu using banshee/7digital and now on win7/songbird I can't login. Is the account for my Ubuntu One different? I've tried all my email accounts with no luck.

Does Ubuntu One have a special name I can log into?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a separate 7 Digital account to log in with to access your music.

That said, any music you've purchased through the Ubuntu One Music Store is available through your Ubuntu One storage.  We do have a beta version of the Ubuntu One client for Windows, but it doesn't currently handle additional synchronised folders (such as the one used for the music store):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Windows#FAQ

Until that feature is added, your best bet would be to download the files via the web interface at https://one.ubuntu.com/files/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *ubuntu one music* store via this link in your browser:

DE: http://stores.7digital.com/default.aspx?shop=265&partner=983
UK: http://stores.7digital.com/default.aspx?shop=6&partner=983
EU: http://stores.7digital.com/default.aspx?shop=436&partner=983
US: http://stores.7digital.com/default.aspx?shop=480&partner=983
Rest of world: [http://stores.7digital.com/default.aspx?shop=496&partner=983](http://stores.7digital.com/default.aspx?shop=496&partner=983e)

Comment: Presumably this adds the music files to your Ubuntu One space?

Answer (score 1):

The online music store is now available [officially](http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2012/09/11/ubuntu-one-music-store-now-on-the-web-and-on-your-mobile/). Just go to [one.ubuntu.com](http://one.ubuntu.com), log in and you'll get access to the music store.